# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException No value given for one or more required parameters?

Tags: vb.net

Here is my code not sure what is wrong with it I've checked everything is spelt correctly in the database as well. I get this exact error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: No value given for one or more required
>   parameters.

```
Private Sub SearchSurname(Secondname As String)
    If DbConnect() Then
        lstCustomers_Customerform.Items.Clear()
        Dim SQLCmd As New OleDbCommand
        With SQLCmd
            .Connection = cn
            .CommandText = "Select * From [Tbl_Customer] Where [Secondname] Like @SurnameSearch"
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@SurnameSearch", "%" & txtLastname_Search.Text & "%")

            Dim rs As OleDbDataReader = .ExecuteReader
            While rs.Read
                Dim DisplayValue As String = rs("[Firstname]") & " " & rs("[Secondname]") & " (" & rs("[DOB]") & ")"
                Dim CustItem As New Listboxdata(DisplayValue, rs("[CustomerID]"))
                lstCustomers_Customerform.Items.Add(CustItem)

            End While
            rs.Close()

            If lstCustomers_Customerform.Items.Count > 1 Then
                'Show list 
                PanSearchList.Visible = True

            Else
                PanSearchList.Visible = False

            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I upvoted because you are using `Parameters` and that makes me happy

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said which Database server you are actually connecting to, this is important because if its MS Sql Server, MySQL, or Oracle there are custom version of the Data Access classes which you would be better off using.

However, to address your problem directly:

The `OleDb` data providers don't like named parameters like `@name`. They require simple `?` place holders for where the parameters are to appear.

Chang your CommandText to be:

```
.CommandText = "Select * From [Tbl_Customer] Where [Secondname] Like ?"
```

If you carry on using an `OleDb` provider, you will need to make sure that whenever you use Parameters (which should EVERY time), then that the parameters are added to the command object in the correct order as expected in the Sql statement.

Note. If you are connecting to a MS Sql Server database and using the `SqlClient` data providers your code would've worked without a problem.